# Python ctags dictionary entries

Tags: python, dictionary, ctags

My PI has an interesting style of coding when he uses python, he puts all of his variables and functions into dictionaries, and calls functions through dictionaries rather than calling the actual function. Example:

```
# Setup
def test():
    print('test')
D = dict()
D['test'] = test
# Calling the function
D['test']()
```

Problem is that this makes his code difficult to read, since the function declaration and calls are in different files. Normally I use ctags to read difficult to parse code, but ctags doesn't treat dictionary entries in python as tags, so I can't jump to declaration of these tags or functions. Is there some way I can setup ctags to parse these dictionary entries as tags?

Comment: A dictionary can hold pretty much anything and you cannot expect any parser to fully interpret your code just to figure out what some smartass decided to store in it (also, I think you meant `D['test'] = test`, but that's of a little consequence here). How about you tell whoever is using this (abhorrent) 'style' to stop being a jerk?

Comment: @zwer: PI = Principal Investigator = boss

Comment: He uses the dictionaries as a replacement for an object, as he doesn't like Python's implemention of OOP. Most of our codebase is written this way though at this point I'm debating doing a complete rewrite in a separate branch.

Comment: @BoarGules - bosses can be jerks, too, and it should be pointed out to them.

Comment: @SauhaardaChowdhuri - he's using the language in a way it was not meant to be used, breaking pretty much any convention along the way and trying to re-Python Python (he's aware that Python stores properties in a dict underneath anyway, right?). If he didn't like Python that much why did he opt for it in the first place? Either way, without fully interpreting your code any parser/editor/typehinter cannot know what a dict holds to know where it's sourced from. Sure, a special case for this sort of thing (given the manual assignment) can be written but why bother with specialized cases?